# why AVL tree max height given N is 1.44log(N+2)-1.328

Tags: algorithm, tree, avl-tree

we know that in worst case `S(h)=S(h-1)+S(h-2)+1`,I've also seen [Evan Bechtol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769383/finding-the-minimum-and-maximum-height-in-a-avl-tree-given-a-number-of-nodes),but there's no obvious deduction there. How to get the [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgX19.png)      from`S(h)=S(h-1)+S(h-2)+1`?

Comment: Hint: the S(h) formula looks almost like the formula for Fibonacci numbers. Perhaps you know how to derive Fibonacci numbers from matrix equations, and can adapt the proof?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a modification of the Fibonacci sequence, you might want to look at Binet's formula that refers to the Golden ratio. The deductive proof can be found [here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-23/lectures/notes/AVL.txt).